# Using a function from another file to write to excel with xlsx

Tags: python, excel, xlsx

I have two python files:

1- writerCode.py:

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('demo.xlsx')
ws = workbook.add_worksheet()

def writeTo(x,y,array):
    j = 0
    while j < (len(array)):
        ws.write(x,y,array[j])
        j +=1
        x +=1
    return;

workbook.close()
```

2- testingCode.py:

```
from writerCode import *
an = ['123','234','123','432','123']
writeTo(0,0,an)
```

I want to import an[] items to excel.

When I run testingCode.py it creates 'demo.xlsx' with NOTHING in it. The excel file is empty meaning that it does not import an[] to the excel file as intended.

I was wondering if anybody knows what the problem is??

Comment: you should learn about indentation in `Python`

Comment: also use `for`-loop instead of ugly `while`-loop

Comment: @AzatIbrakov - while loops are not ugly.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Fixed the indentations.

Comment: @wwii: usage of it in given context is considered ugly and non-Pythonic

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not "Using a function from another file"

> The excel file is empty meaning that it does not import an[] to the excel file as intended.

It could also mean that the part of your code controlling Excel does not work.

test2.py:

```
def mydef(d):
    print(d)
```

test.py:

```
from test2 import *
data = "hello"
mydef(data)
```

results in

```
hello
```

So it's not that.

It's probably that you are closing your workbook right after you open it.
All the code is run on import, except for the function.

Ugly quick fix (restructure your code):

```
workbook.close()
```

*after* calling `writeTo()`.

---

[`xlsxwriter`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter) should be raising an Exception when a closed Workbook/Worksheet is being written to, but it doesn't:

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('demo.xlsx')
ws = workbook.add_worksheet()
workbook.close()
ws.write(0,0,"hello")
```

indeed results in a valid XSLX file with no data in the cell.

Answer (score 1):

> You are trying to import closed Workbook in `testingCode.py`, you can't write to a closed workbook.

So, replace `workbook.close()` to `testingCode.py`. That way you are closing workbook after calling the function `writeTo(x, y, array)`.

And try to use `for` loop, because `while` loop works but makes your code looks bit complex to read. And make your code looks neat by adding spaces after `,`. These spaces makes your code more readable.

```
def writeTo(x, y, array):
    for item in (array):
        ws.write(x, y, item)
        x += 1
```